# MySQL equivalent to .pgpass, or automatic authentication in a cron job for mySQL

Tags: backup, bash, cron, mysql

I'm writing a bash script to back up my databases. Most are postgresql, and in postgres there's a way to avoid having to authenticate by creating a ~/.pgpass file which contains the postgres password. I put this in root's home directory and made it chmod 0600, so that root could dump the postgres databases without having to authenticate. Now I want to do something similar for mysql, although I only have one mysql database. How can I do this? I don't want to specify the password on the command line for mysqldump because this is part of a script that might be somewhat visible to other users. Is there a better way (i.e. built in to mysql) to do this than make a file that only root can read and then read that to get the mysql password, and then use that in the bash script as a variable?

Comment: Hmm, strangely, I found something promising through google rather than serverfault's own search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601995/secure-mysql-backup-cron-job--my-cnf-is-not-being-read

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/110738/using-mysqldump-in-cron-job-without-root-password

Comment: And http://serverfault.com/questions/56341/mysqldump-prompting-for-password-in-shellscript/56345#56345

Comment: Yeah bleh, apparently my search-fu is lacking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `~/.my.cnf` file for the user running mysql.  It should contain the following:

```
[client]
user = root
password = yourpassword
```

Comment: One thing I guess to add is that if running the script using sudo, you need to use -H to make sure that it uses root's home directory. But I think that problem shouldn't be an issue in a root cron job, correct?

Comment: But how is that handled for multiple accounts? That'll work for localhost, but what if I want to store my login for a remote server?