# Store the MySQL client password, or setup password less authentication

Tags: mysql

I am using the mysql command line client and I do not want to need to provide the password every time I start the client.  What are my options?

Comment: Please accept answers on some of your previous questions, as it appears that several of those answers have been correct solutions - click the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Create a file named `.my.cnf` in your home directory that looks like this.   Make sure the filesystem permissions are set such that only the owning user can read it (0600).

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = username.
password = thepassword
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#database = mysql
```

Since you also tagged your question mysqldump you should look at this question.

[Using mysqldump in cron job without root password](https://serverfault.com/questions/110738/using-mysqldump-in-cron-job-without-root-password/110747#110747)

Update (2016-06-29) If you are running mysql 5.6.6 or greater, you should look at the [mysql_config_editor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html) tool that allows you to [store credentials](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/08/16/understanding-mysql_config_editors-security-aspects/) in an encrypted file.  Thanks to [Giovanni](https://serverfault.com/a/786944/984) for mentioning this to me.

Comment: This is great it worked .. Thanku

Comment: If the answer solved your problem then you should click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: This will store the password as plain text, a practice that I would discourage from a security point of view.

Comment: @Giovanni sure, though the mysql_config_editor you mention in your answer, while useful isn't available until you are running 5.6.6.  There are still distributions today that have older versions.

Comment: But how is this done on Windows?

Comment: Not really sure, how it works on windows.  It sure seems likely that it would use the same filename/format.  But I have never tried.

Comment: Please note that config editor only obfuscates and doesn't really encrypt. MariaDB is not including the feature because it gives a false sense of security.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `mysql_config_editor` utility to store authentication credentials in an encrypted login path file named `.mylogin.cnf`.

To create a new set of credentials run:

```
mysql_config_editor set --host=db.host.org --user=dbuser --password
```

and enter your password when prompted.

This will store your authentication credentials in the default `client` login path.

You can store multiple authentication credentials by specifying a different `--login-path` option:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=db2 --host=db2.host.org --user=dbuser --password
```

By default, the `mysql` client reads the `[client]` and `[mysql]` groups from other option files, so it reads them from the login path file as well. With a `--login-path` option, client programs additionally read the named login path from the login path file. The option groups read from other option files remain the same. Consider this command:

```
mysql --login-path=db2
```

The `mysql` client reads `[client]` and `[mysql]` from other option files, and `[client]`, `[mysql]`, and `[mypath]` from the login path file.

To print out all the information stored in the configuration file run:

```
mysql_config_editor print --all=true
```

More information about the utility can be found at ["mysql_config_editor — MySQL Configuration Utility"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Answer (score 4):

We must not pretend that the *.mylogin.cnf* is secure at all since I can use `my_print_defaults -s [use your login-path]` to make that password appear in plain text.  This is why MariaDB does not support this 'security by obscurity' approach.

Comment: So what ***is*** the answer to this question then?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, orthogonal to the methods mentioned above, *but it can be a security risk if someone else is watching your monitor, OR if you are saving your history*.

Nevertheless it is an option, which will prevent you from being prompted, and one which I use in throw-away docker images and such....

```
mysql -u YOUR_USER --password=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE your_database -e "your query" etc.
```

You will not be prompted, you can set a temporary alias in the shell if you wish.

Use with caution.

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.61-38.13, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1