# Backup MySQL databases in 1 file but with separated .tar.gz for each db

Tags: mysql, backup, database

I'm now using this in cron to backup all my databases in 1 sql.gz file:

```
0 0     * * *   root    mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --all-databases | gzip > /home/backup/db/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`_db.sql.gz
```

I'd like to have one .tar.gz file within whom X other archives for how many databases I have..
Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/ is something for you. You would only have to zip the whole folder structure this script generates. You can do this with a post-script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this may work.  It is un-tested, but only slightly different from what I am using for backups on my systems.

```
# define common vars
OPTIONS="--verbose --lock-tables --flush-logs --force --quick --single-transaction"
AUTHFILE="/etc/mysql/rootauth.cnf"
BACKUPDIR="/srv/backup/mysql/"
BACKUPDATE=`date +"%y%m%d%H"`

# create temp folder (this isn't entirely safe, but be sure only root or backup user has 
#                     write access here, you might want to use mktemp)
mkdir ${BACKUPDIR}/tmp/

# get a list of all the databases on the system
DBSQL="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA where SCHEMA_NAME!='information_schema' \
       AND SCHEMA_NAME!='performance_schema' order by SCHEMA_NAME"
DBS=`/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-extra-file=${AUTHFILE} --batch \
                                  --skip-column-names --execute "$DBSQL"`
DBS=`echo $DBS | tr -d '\n' | sed -e "s/ \+/ /g"`

for DB in $DBS; do
  # perform a per-database dump
  BACKUPDIRDB="${BACKUPDIR}/tmp/${DB}"
  mkdir -p ${BACKUPDIRDB}
  /usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=${AUTHFILE} \
       ${OPTIONS} $DB > ${BACKUPDIRDB}/backup_${BACKUPDATE}
done

# create archive of everything
tar -czvf ${BACKUPDIR}/backup_${BACKUPDATE}.tar.gz ${BACKUPDIR}/tmp/ 
#remove temp files
rm -rf ${BACKUPDIR}/tmp/
```

Comment: I'm going to try this and let you know if worked! ;)

Comment: I created a test.sh file in /srv to test it. I run it via "bash /srv/test.sh" but I got this result:

/srv/test.sh: line 16: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/srv/test.sh: line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think I may have lost a backtick (`) on my copy and paste into the editor here.  Check like 16 and line 30 and make sure the quotes are all properly balanced and closed.

Comment: I think I found it, I'm testing it again. ;)

Comment: Could not open required defaults file: /etc/mysql/rootauth.cnf
Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/srv/backup/mysql//tmp/

I don't have the file /etc/mysql/rootauth.cnf, I have my.cnf, should I replace it with that?

Comment: the file rootauth.cnf is meant to be a standard mysql config file for storing credentials, which is better then passing them on the command line.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/56341/mysqldump-prompting-for-password-in-shellscript/56345#56345

Comment: The script is running, seems to work properly!! Will confirm this when it finishes! ;)

Comment: Yeah!! It works like a charm!! Thanks! :D
Really latest request (if possible): how can I modify the script in order to have the databases in the tar files without the parent directories (for example I have now /srv/backup/mysql//temp and then the DBs)..

Answer (score 5):

Create a script like this to mysqldump all databases in parallel

```
DBLIST=`mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD -ANe"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name) FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" | sed 's/,/ /g'`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="-uroot -pPASSWORD --single-transaction --routines --triggers"
BACKUP_DEST=/home/backup/db/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`
mkdir ${BACKUP_DEST}
for DB in `echo "${DBLIST}"`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_DEST}/${DB}.sql.gz &
done
wait
```

Then place this script in the crontab

If there are way too many databases, you could dump 5 at a time like this

```
DBLIST=`mysql -uroot -pPASSWORD -ANe"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name) FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" | sed 's/,/ /g'`
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="-uroot -pPASSWORD --single-transaction --routines --triggers"
BACKUP_DEST=/home/backup/db/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`
mkdir ${BACKUP_DEST}
COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=5
for DB in `echo "${DBLIST}"`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_DEST}/${DB}.sql.gz &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

You can then add the tar commands to the script

Comment: I don't have the file /tmp/DBList.txt :(
Yeah as Zoredache said I'd like 1 big archive with files per-db inside, sorry for my poor explanation..

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 and MySQL 5.5.24, if useful :)

Comment: I changed my answer to not use /tmp/DBList.txt

Comment: Probably it's my fault.. I created a .sh file with your script (first one). Then I run it from the terminal but I got this:
line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Okay, found the error. I fixed it and started the script, I get no errors but nothing happens.. the file doesn't get created.. :(

Comment: My script had a backtick missing. Please try again...

Comment: I tried the new script. I get no errors now but the file isn't created in the folder (/home/backup/db/) ..

Comment: Doh  http://www.profilebrand.com/funny-pictures/category/demotivational/114_face-palm-star-trek.gif !!!! I forgot the `mkdir ${BACKUP_DEST}` Please try it now.

Comment: The '2012-07-17' folder gets created.. unfortunately there's no content in it.

Comment: Did you put the correct password in MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS ???

Comment: Yes, of course. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4148/discussion-between-rolandomysqldba-and-multiformeingegno)

Comment: Now it works this too!! :D

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you could accomplish it by making a script that runs from the cron that performs a dump of each database and then the final operation of the script archives all of the files together into one .tar.gz

So in your instance, you would remove the `--all-databases` option and put the name of a database there. Then repeat that line for all the databases you have. Then after all the dumps have been made, create a tar with all those files and zip it up. Last but not least, perform any necessary cleanup. Put all of that into a script and then run the script from cron.

Comment: Yeah I thought of doing so, I was looking for a solution to "dump 'em all" without having to add a line for all of them (also because I add new DBs often and I'm worried to not remember to add one of them).. thanks anyway for the reply! ;)