# cronjob executing mysql and get root access denied

Tags: mysql, cron

cron job file:

```
46 13 * * * root /home/tmp/test_mysql.sh
```

script:

```
execute_query(){
    query="$1"
     res=`mysql --skip-column-names -e "$query"`
    echo "$res"
}

res=`execute_query "show databases"`
echo $res
```

error I got from when cron job executes the script successfully:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I can execute the script successfully from command line as root because the login credential for mysql are saved in /root/.my.cnf
what's wrong?  is cronjob somehow not reading /root/.my.cnf?

Comment: This [link](http://serverfault.com/a/56345/377275) contains an example of how your my.cnf file should look like.

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on MySQL client to pick up the appropriate MySQL configuration file because of the [cascading nature](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html) of how the client is reading those files. Instead you should put both your `my.cnf` and `test_mysql.sh` inside `/home/tmp` and use `--defaults-extra-file` [[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/option-file-options.html#option_general_defaults-extra-file)] parameter in your script.

Do take note, the `--defaults-extra-file` needs to be the **first** argument of your mysql command otherwise it won't work.

```
execute_query(){
    query="$1"
     res=`mysql --defaults-extra-file=/home/tmp/my.cnf --skip-column-names -e "$query"`
    echo "$res"
}

res=`execute_query "show databases"`
echo $res
```

`/root` is not a very good place to put stuff in (permissions etc.) and should be avoided.

Running scripts that interact with a MySQL server should also be performed with a non-privileged user.